# Como hago para que el Inventario se siga Reduciendo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando una consulta que arroja la siente tabla como resultado:

[image: Tabla]

La columna **Initial_Inventory** se tiene que ir disminuyendo con lo que tiene la columna **Need_QTY** y asi hacia abajo.

Todo es en SQL.

Mi version de SQL es:

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU7-GDR) (KB4505222) - 13.0.5366.0 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 08:22:25   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 Standard 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tp ') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #tp
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#A ') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #A

   select * into #tp from  openrowset('SQLNCLI', 'Server=GDJNT421\SQLFF4;Initial 
   Catalog=P_repALU_IPD;UID=ffreporting;PWD=reporting2k8',
    'select Company,Line,PartNumber,PlanDate,Shift,Area,PlanQTY,PlanType
     from P_repALU_IPD.dbo.udtThroughtputPlan tp
     where cast(tp.PlanDate as date) >= cast(getdate () as date)
     order by tp.PlanDate asc')

      select tp.*,bom.Child,bom.Mat_Type,bom.LVL Bom_Lvl,BOM.Quantity 
      Bom_Qty,bom.Phantom, PlanQTY*BOM.Quantity Need_QTY,
      ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by bom.Child order by tp.PlanDate asc  ) 
      RowNumber into #A

      from #tp tp left join 
      udtCascadeBOMMultiLevel bom on bom.TOP_PARENT = tp.PartNumber

      where plantype = 'Congelado' and PartNumber = 'ALC5H-3HE10717CA' and bom.Phantom = 'N'

      order by plandate asc


      select A.*,Inv.Qty Initial_Inventory,Inv.Qty-A.Need_QTY AvailableQTY,
      lag(Inv.Qty-A.Need_QTY,1) OVER (PARTITION BY A.Child ORDER BY A.PlanDate
   )  next_month_sales

   from #A A left join

   (select ITEM, sum(QTY) as Qty, WhsClassificationPulse 
   from udtCascadeINV
   where WhsClassificationPulse = 'Store'
    group by ITEM,WhsClassificationPulse) Inv on Inv.ITEM = A.CHILD  and A.RowNumber = 1

   where A.CHILD = 'ALC5H-10-0012-01'
   order by A.PlanDate,a.PartNumber asc
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Tienes puntos de reputación que indican que conoces el funcionamiento del sitio. Puedes agregar la consulta sql? Y cuál sería el resultado de salida?

Comment: @Bicho, agrego la consulta pero el resultado es la imagen que vez. igual lo pongo como tabla.